# Spring modules can use other module port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, module, get-request

In my project I created two modules, frontend-module and backend-module, where frontend is responsible for user interface and backend for API and other stuff.

```
frontend-module/
└── src/
    └── main/
        └── java/
            └── com/
                └── example/
                    └── application/
                        ├── pages/
                        ├── components/
                        └── scripts/

backend-module/
└── src/
    └── main/
        └── java/
            └── com/
                └── example/
                    └── application/
                        ├── controllers/
                        ├── services/
                        ├── repositories/
                        ├── entities/
                        └── dtos/
```

So I set up ports for each module, where:

**Frontend**

```
server.port=${PORT:3008}
```

**Backend**

```
server.port=${PORT:8008}
```

---

When I start application, I do start both modules `frontend` and `backend`, and this is what I found. For some reason, I can access `backend`'s module API from `frontend` port. Another interesting thing that I can successfully run just frontend module without backend, and everything will work properly. So my question is, why this is happening and how can I prevent this.

**Backend port**

[image: 8008 port]

**Frontend port**

[image: 3008 port]

---

**Additional information**

- Frontend module is dependent on backend module.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

- My perfect scenario is having independent API, and dependent front from backend. Where I can secure my API in a way and front on other way.
- For this case, on accessing URL `localhost:3008/api/get` should give not found page
- Template GitHub URL - https://github.com/Alexenon/SpringModules

Answer (score 0):

When you imported **backend-module** to **front-end module** - you just added all entire codebase from backend to frontend, which means that **frontend will have its own @RestController and will run copy of that routes**.

[image]

If you want independency between FE and BE - you have to make it via REST API using [Feign](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html) or other similar library. (FE will call HTTP call to BE)

---

P.S
You can even create 3 module which will contain libraries and code for communication between services.

---

P.P.S. If you use Vaadin - i would recommend to take a look at [Hilla.dev](https://hilla.dev/) by Vaadin. In by opinion its much more straightforward and native way of developing both FE and BE side.